# How to call form several time but with diffrent variables!-C#-Winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, variables, dynamic, call

I am new  to C#.Winform.
I stuck in the situation where i want to call confirmation form from 5 different buttons event.Like Train ticket confirmation button,vehicle book button, flight book button.
But on clicking each button i want to call (let say form2) but each time with different context!
Like when i call from train ticket.(User info and payment info on form).
When i call from flight(User info and flight booking info on form).

---

How i do this!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't "call" a class. You might create an instance of a class, or call a method in a class. It sounds like in this case you may just want to call the constructor, passing different arguments depending on the context:

```
using (Form2 form2 = new Form2(userInfo, flightBookingInfo))
{
    form2.ShowDialog();
}
```

(Or whatever you need to do, of course... this was just a guess.)

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, at this stage of your programming skill level, I'd suggest you create seperate forms for each kind of confirmation.  There are certainly ways to reuse a single form for something like this, but to do that well may be a bit more advanced than you're current skill level.

There's a concept called the Single Responsibility Principle, which says that any object should only do one thing.  While it's possible to fit SRP into this scenario, like I said it would take a lot more knowledge of how things work than you likely have right now (I say this based only on the way you phrased your question).

Keep things simple, make a FlightConfirmationForm, and a TrainConfirmationForm.  Maybe you can share some common code between them and derive from a common ancestor.  And, as your skills grow, you can look into ways to refactor and simplify the system.

Comment: Wow! Thanks :) But i am curious about re usability.

Comment: @user656929 - I understand, but it's very easy to create an unmaintainable mess if you aren't careful.  Making each form seperate will make yoru code easier to manage and maintain in the short term.  As your knowledge grows, you can start looking into ways to make your code more reusable.

Comment: Thanks .I will take care of your words :)